# Which WinAPI function set last error to ERROR_SUCCESS if no error occured?

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling

There is a large legacy codebase which seems to fail in some hard to reproduce and investigate situation.

It calls some WinAPI function, say, [CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx), and instead of checking the return code, checks `GetLastError()` value. I know this is wrong, but it would be really nice to know whether non-null last error value originates from this call or something that happened earlier. If I was sure that `CopyFile` sets last error to `ERROR_SUCCESS` in case everything went well, it would be enough to conclude that this specific call failed.

MSDN mentions that some functions do this and some do not but does not tell specifically which ones do. Is there some unofficial list/reference which covers this question?

Comment: `GetLastError()` usage is documented on a per-function basis.  MOST functions that set the last error DO NOT set it on success, only on failure.  Functions that DO set the last error on success are also *documented* as doing so and under which conditions.  There is no single master list that documents which functions act which way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, that's all I wanted to know. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GetLastError()` usage is documented on a per-function basis.  There is no single master list that documents which functions act which way in regards to `GetLastError()`.  If any given function is not documented as setting the last error, **do not** use `GetLastError()` to check the last error after the function exits.

Most functions that do set the last error **do not** set it on success, only on failure, and are documented as such.

Functions that **do** set the last error on success are documented as such, and will also document which success conditions set the last error to which value.  This is *typically* used in cases where a function's return value is ambiguous as to whether the function succeeded or failed, so `GetLastError()` is used to differentiate.  For instance, most functions return 0 on failure, but some functions may return 0 on success and failure. In such cases, if `GetLastError()` then returns 0 (or a defined success code) then the function succeeded, otherwise the function failed.  `GetTLSValue()` is one example of this.

A notable exception to this are functions that create named kernel objects (`CreateMutex()`, `CreateEvent()`, `CreateSemaphore()`, etc).  They return a non-zero value on success, but also `GetLastError()` will return either 0 or  `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` depending on whether the function returns a handle to a newly-created object or an existing object.  This is documented accordingly for each function.

Comment: Another random example: `TlsGetValue()` returns the TLS value on success, 0 on failure. It sets last error to `ERROR_SUCCESS` on success to distinguish the "TLS value was 0" case from the error cases.

Comment: @keithmo: yes, that would fall into the "*some functions may return 0 on success and failure*" portion of my answer. But I have now added `GetTLSValue()` as an example.